# Remove C# Escape Character

Tags: c#, excel, escaping, vsto, formula

I am having a problem when working with VSTO's Evaluate function, that function is basically translating a formula in Excel and return the value.

What I am struggling is if I pass a formula with " character, C# automatically add \ next to it, I do understand why it is there, but it is causing the function to fail since the \ character is trying to get evaluate as well, but if I use the string Replace function to remove the \ character, it works.

However, I cannot just remove \ character, what if the user do type a \ character on a cell? I will remove that regardless and causing my solution to give a wrong answer.

Can anyone help me to resolve that?

I have tried to use the @ sign, doesn't work neither.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: You could replace \" with " instead of \ with <empty> ?  If the user enters a \ and it is escaping as you say wouldn't that too get escaped to \\ ?    Here are some of the escape chars http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Post the code that's being called please?

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xl = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
element = xl.ActiveCell.Formula;
string result = xl.Evaluate(element.ToString()).Value.ToString();

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are just seeing the \ character in the debugger.  Nothing that I have ever seen in C# automatically inserts the escape character in any strings.  Can you give us some example code?

Comment: Hi Chris, I am seeing the \ character in debugger mode, but if I replace \ with empty string, the code work perfectly, without doing that, it will throws an error.